# How to use peewee with scrapinghub

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I want to save my data to remote machine by using peewee. When i run my crawler i found following error,

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 163, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1445, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/annuaire_agence_bio/pipelines.py", line 8, in <module>

exceptions.ImportError: No module named peewee
```

Any suggestions is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install module of your own choice on Scrapinhub ... You can only install MySQLDB as per my knowledge, to do that.

Create a file named `scrapinghub.yml` in your project's main folder with following contents.

```
projects:
  default: 111149
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

Where `111149` is my proejct ID on scrapinghub.

Create another file named `requirements.txt` in same directory.

and put your required modules along with the version number you are using in that file like so,

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

**PS:** I was using MySQLDB module so I put that.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the first sentence. In fact, you can install any module of your choice on Scrapinghub.

Comment: Just add peewee to the requirements.txt